# Change brightness of Image with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I have a such code:

```
private Image image;

public void paint(GraphicsContext g, double x, double y) {
    if (image == null) return;
    g.drawImage(image, x, y);
}
```

How to change chage brightness and then draw the image?
I am aware about `ColorAdjust` effect and `ImageView`, but how to use it in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `ColorAdjust` effect on the `GraphicsContext` object with [`setEffect(Effect)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setEffect-javafx.scene.effect.Effect-):

```
public void paint(GraphicsContext g, double x, double y) {
    if (image == null) return;

    ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
    colorAdjust.setBrightness(0.1);
    g.setEffect(colorAdjust);

    g.drawImage(image, x, y);
}
```